# The loading another class has side effect with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3

Can somebody explain me this:

```
User < AbstractUser
  store_in collection: 'users'

InvitedUser < AbstractUser
  store_in collection: 'invited_users'
```

Then when I am loading the InvitedUser while working with a user object I have the following side effect.

```
[3] pry(#<UserInvitationsController>)> User.collection
=> #<Moped::Collection:0x007f8f008f21e0
  ...
@name="users">
[4] pry(#<UserInvitationsController>)> InvitedUser
=> false
[5] pry(#<UserInvitationsController>)> User.collection
=> #<Moped::Collection:0x007f8f00202d30
@name="invited_users">
```

And from then on the mongoid operations on User won't work properly...

I also reported an issue on github:
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the side effect is caused by the common ancestor.

Without common ancestor everything is like it should be.

```
=> User
[2] pry(main)> User.collection.name
=> "users"
[3] pry(main)> InvitedUser.collection.name
=> "invited_users"
[4] pry(main)> User.collection.name
=> "users"
[5] pry(main)> InvitedUser.collection.name
=> "invited_users"
[6] pry(main)> exit
```

With common ancestor the side effect appears

```
→ ./bin/rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
[1] pry(main)> User.collection.name
=> "users"
[2] pry(main)> InvitedUser.collection.name
=> "invited_users"
[3] pry(main)> User.collection.name
=> "invited_users"
[4] pry(main)> InvitedUser.collection.name
=> "invited_users"
[5] pry(main)>
```